# If $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k+y_k}\leqslant\frac n2$, prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{x_k}{1+y_k}+\frac{y_k}{1+x_k})\geqslant n$

Tags: inequality, fractions

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geqslant 2$ and $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n>0$ with $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{ 1 \over{x_k+y_k} }  \leqslant {n\over 2}.$$
>   Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left({ x_k \over{1+y_k} }+{y_k\over{ 1+x_k}}\right)  \geqslant n.$$

I have tried a lot of ways, but I cannot find a good solution. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.  See "How to ask a good question" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 4):

For each $k$,\begin{align*}
\frac{x_k}{1 + y_k} + \frac{y_k}{1 + x_k} &= \frac{(x_k + y_k + 1)(x_k + y_k + 2)}{(1 + x_k)(1 + y_k)} - 2\\
&\geqslant \frac{(x_k + y_k + 1)(x_k + y_k + 2)}{\dfrac{1}{4}((1 + x_k) + (1 + y_k))^2} - 2 = \frac{2(x_k + y_k)}{x_k + y_k + 2},
\end{align*}
thus$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( \frac{x_k}{1 + y_k} + \frac{y_k}{1 + x_k} \right) \geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2(x_k + y_k)}{x_k + y_k + 2}.
$$

By Cauchy's inequality,\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{2}{x_k + y_k} \right) \right) \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2(x_k + y_k)}{x_k + y_k + 2} \right)\\
&= \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{2}{x_k + y_k} \right) \right) \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2}{1 + \frac{2}{x_k + y_k}} \right) \geqslant \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \sqrt{2} \right)^2 = 2n^2,
\end{align*}
and by condition,$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{2}{x_k + y_k} \right) = n + \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2}{x_k + y_k} \leqslant 2n,
$$
thus$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \left( \frac{x_k}{1 + y_k} + \frac{y_k}{1 + x_k} \right) \geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{2(x_k + y_k)}{x_k + y_k + 2} \geqslant n.
$$

Comment: I'd like to know why this answer is downvoted. Care to explain?

Comment: If there's no factual error, such downvoting is quite irresponsible.

Comment: The answer it’s good sir and i upvoted

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine, the issue probably relies in the original question, which lacks any effort from the OP. There is no widespread consensus on the matter, but many users downvote bad questions *and* their answers quite often.

Comment: upvoted for the nice answer. The down voter is just jealous of it.

Comment: Well done. (+1)